# How I can book LHR to TLV at the price shown by ITA Matrix?

Tags: bookings, ita-matrix

I've been trying unsuccessfully to book a round trip flight from London Heathrow, UK (LHR) to Ben Gurion, Israel (TLV) leaving on Dec 24 and returning on Jan 3. I'm seeing this on ITA Matrix but cannot find it on any booking site for less than $832.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can book these flights at this rate?

[image: ITA]

Comment: The typical advice is to take the ITA printout to a travel agent and have them book the ticket. There may be city-of-sale restrictions on the fare that prevents it from being sold online (or, for that matter, in your location).

Comment: Would a travel agent be able to book it if its not able to be sold in my location? Is there any way for me to get around location restrictions?

Comment: El Al shows 521 pounds.

Comment: Information on ITA Matrix seems to be outdated but there are flights to be had for even cheaper than that.

Comment: Skyscanner finds [even cheaper flights](http://www.skyscanner.com/transport/flights/lond/tlv/151224/160103/airfares-from-london-to-ben-gurion-intl-in-december-2015-and-january-2016.html?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=true&inboundaltsenabled=true)...

Answer (score 4):

ITA is not giving you accurate information, unfortunately. The present availability on those flights as seen in London is—

```
                                                                 Frequency
Flight        Stops  Depart             Arrive             Aircraft  Reliability     Available Classes

LY 318        0      LHR                TLV                772       Su,Th,Sa        F6 AL PL C9 I5 D2 ZL JL RL XL Y9 S9 M9 Q9 B9 K9 V9 L9 H9 NL GC OC UC WC EL 
                     24/12/15 22:30     25/12/15 5:20                75% / 15m

LY 315        0      TLV                LHR                772       Su,M,T,W,Th,F   F6 AL PL C9 I9 D8 ZL JL RL XL Y9 S9 M9 Q9 B9 KL V1 LL HL NL GC OC UC WC EL 
                     03/01/16 9:05      03/01/16 12:35               52% / 28m
```

In both cases, the W class is closed to reservations (WC); therefore the fare ITA selected (LY **W**UKRT5) is no longer valid over the sectors.

If you wish you may report this as a bug to ITA Support. I have found the support team quite helpful in respect of other problems I have had with ITA.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Is there a chance that seats would open up in the future at that price?

Comment: @user32166 It's possible, but because of the time of year I think it is not very likely the airline will have difficulty selling seats.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this is just sold out in this fare class. ITA does a lot of caching to speed things up and may show fares that used to be available but are no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Actually these flights show up on [Orbitz](http://www.orbitz.com/shop/airsearch?type=air&ar.type=roundTrip&ar.rt.numAdult=1&ar.rt.leaveSlice.time=Anytime&ar.rt.leaveSlice.dest.key=TLV&ar.rt.leaveSlice.orig.key=LON&ar.rt.returnSlice.time=Anytime&ar.rt.leaveSlice.date=12/24/15&ar.rt.returnSlice.date=01/03/16&search=Search&WT.mc_ev=click&gcid=17503&utm_campaign=Google%20-%20ORBAir%20-%20Sponsored%20Search%20Ads&utm_medium=Travel%20Research/Deals&utm_source=Google&strm=true&lpid.ruleId=900001400&lpid.category=air-route-dated&lpid.priority=1400.0&lpid=airGpSearch) though the carrier isn't ElAl and the flight is from Gatwick rather then Heathrow and with a single stop but depending on your circumstances it may not matter.